# DYLD, Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSConstantIntegerNumber

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

My iOS app project is crashing in old iPhone devices (6 Plus), and I cannot find any way to fix it. Could anyone help?

The app just crashed when it launches.

The following is portion of the crash log (there is text limitation here).

Full log is here: https://pastebin.com/VSnrrx0c

```
Incident Identifier: CC04AA95-1087-4875-B802-9861C7FF9CE1
CrashReporter Key:   6655fc4cfd2e5cf7ad4e91e2fba51e530e23ed07
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             Meeeet [393]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Meeeet
Identifier:          com.meeeet.Meeeet
Version:             231 (8.0.0)
AppStoreTools:       13E500a
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.meeeet.Meeeet [460]


Date/Time:           2022-09-02 11:54:07.8221 +0800
Launch Time:         2022-09-02 11:54:07.7359 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.5.5 (16H62)
Baseband Version:    7.80.04
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSConstantIntegerNumber | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Meeeet | Expected in: dyld shared cache | in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Meeeet
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00000001030e2418 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   dyld                            0x00000001030e1a58 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2   dyld                            0x00000001030e1a88 fcntl + 0
3   dyld                            0x00000001030a48f8 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol+ 18680 (ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 0
4   dyld                            0x00000001030a76e4 dyld::_main+ 30436 (macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 5396
5   dyld                            0x00000001030a1044 _dyld_start + 68

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000004   x2: 0x000000016f2269b0   x3: 0x00000000000000a2
    x4: 0x000000016f2265b0   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x000000016f226d80
    x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x433842463935342d  x11: 0x6f4d2f3344324342
   x12: 0x3935342d33323439  x13: 0x4432434243384246  x14: 0x612e65766f4d2f33  x15: 0x0065766f4d2f7070
   x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000016f2265b0  x21: 0x00000000000000a2  x22: 0x000000016f2269b0  x23: 0x0000000000000004
   x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x000000000000002f  x26: 0x00000001030fb5e0  x27: 0x00000001030fb000
   x28: 0x00000001030fba00   fp: 0x000000016f226580   lr: 0x00000001030e1a58
    sp: 0x000000016f226540   pc: 0x00000001030e2418 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100bd8000 - 0x10297ffff Meeeet arm64  <b55212af4b9e3c449d35272d5b483faf> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Meeeet
0x102f7c000 - 0x102f8ffff TTTAttributedLabel arm64  <0a09d832609b3883b9aba76916d82c68> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Frameworks/TTTAttributedLabel.framework/TTTAttributedLabel
0x102fac000 - 0x102ff7fff MNLWebAuthn arm64  <e81494e144403ddbb6523031932238e0> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Frameworks/MNLWebAuthn.framework/MNLWebAuthn
0x103040000 - 0x103067fff DSAModule arm64  <7656a4cd9d463c08b912809c9c6a5173> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Frameworks/DSAModule.framework/DSAModule
0x103080000 - 0x103087fff UICountingLabel arm64  <35d477328df93f9390a7c35424bdb9d3> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Frameworks/UICountingLabel.framework/UICountingLabel
0x1030a0000 - 0x1030f7fff dyld arm64  <c08f675c016c30b8a87de35aef8f6b20> /usr/lib/dyld
0x103160000 - 0x1031e3fff RemoteAPIClient arm64  <bd77e4a585e63a909632d05c60fc0645> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Frameworks/RemoteAPIClient.framework/RemoteAPIClient
0x10321c000 - 0x103243fff PromiseKit_34A278A94EE8AA11_PackageProduct arm64  <7e28d579b76834408090b43da0718c12> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Frameworks/PromiseKit_34A278A94EE8AA11_PackageProduct.framework/PromiseKit_34A278A94EE8AA11_PackageProduct
0x103258000 - 0x1032c7fff OneSignal arm64  <f869a0fa9b023395a1f39d3ebbebf1de> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Frameworks/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal
0x103378000 - 0x1033fbfff CryptoSwift_-360922625E627667_PackageProduct arm64  <b213f76f8e1d3ff9ab3ed556e011cf26> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F9D38B3A-BC1F-4131-9423-459FB8CBC2D3/Meeeet.app/Frameworks/CryptoSwift_-360922625E627667_PackageProduct.framework/CryptoSwift_-360922625E627667_PackageProduct
```

Comment: Hi, I am also seeing this crash after upgrading to newer Xcode version. It's only crashing on iOS 12.x versions. Were you able to fix this crash?